# Memory Leak in Crystal Report ASP.net app

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, crystal-reports-2008

I have a simple app running on windows 2008 R2 SP1 with iis7. The application Loads a crystal report, then prints the report to printer using the printtoprinter method. All works fine, but the w3wp.exe is out of control. It reached up to 2GB before I had to manually recycle. there are about 8 people using the site printing atleast 2K of reports to the printer.

After I print the report, I am using .Close and .Dispose of the ReportDocument object. Using ASP.net 3.5

```
Using rptDoc As New ReportDocument

        rptDoc.Load(FilePackList)
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(data)
        rptDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = DropDownPackList.Text
        rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(nCopies, False, 0, 0)
        rptDoc.Close()
        rptDoc.Dispose()
    End Using
```

Any help please as to why it's killing my memory?

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you post the code that you have an issue with.

Comment: Using rptDoc As New ReportDocument
Dim data = da.GetData
rptDoc.Load(xxxx)
rptDoc.SetDataSource(data)
rptDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = ""
rptDoc.PrintToPrinter(nCopies, False, 0, 0) rptDoc.Close rptDoc.Dispose

Comment: You can edit your original question, add the code in there.